# Is there any way to cache a http call in angular when waiting for http response?

Tags: angular, rest, http, caching

We have Angular app, which is calling our REST backend. Some of our requests has a complicated processing on the server side, and may take more than one minute (in some cases). When the reponse is sent back to our front, a table is fill with the backend data. We are trying to improve the user experience here and we are thinking about the following scenario:

1. When the use loads this page for the first time, the table is empty and a loading spinner is displayed (we have no choice here)
2. When the data is received from the backend, the table is rendered and the result is cached somewhere (memory, local storage or whatever in the browser...)
3. When the user asks again for the same page, the data is rendered first from that cache, and the query is sent to the backend
4. A Toast is displayed and saying to the system is working on it, the data are coming soon and the table will be updated
5. When the asynchronous call receives the response from the backend, the table is rendered again with the new data.
6. The new data will update the browser cache

Instead of reinventing the wheel, we are asking here if there is an existing npm module doing that or there is a better idea for doing that.

Bonus/Nice to have: Everytime the data is received, it is hashed and the hash is compared to the previous one. If the hash is different, then whe have to render the table again, otherwise we have nothing to do. That hash or unique responseId can be computed on the backend side

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure any external package would do better than just using the local storage. So you can create a new object with two keyes: responseId and response, set the corresponding backend responses there and store the whole object locally. You can then use its responseId to compare it to what you get from the api. However, once you get the data from the backend, rendering of the table won't take much time, so I personally don't see a need not to update it even if the id is the same, i.e. I think there's no need to store the id and compare it with what you get with new response.

Comment: Honestly, use a state management library